# Data ingestion in Hadoop using Distcp

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume, distcp

I understand that distcp is used for inter/intra cluster transfer of data. Is it possible to use distcp to ingest data from the local file system to HDFS. I understand that you can use file:///....
to point to a local file outside of HDFS but how reliable and fast is that compared to the inter/intra cluster transfer.

Comment: No. Distcp can be use only for transferring data with source and sink as HDFS.

Answer (score 2):

Distcp is a mapreduce job that is executed inside the hadoop cluster. For hadoop cluster perspective, your local machine is not a local file system. Then you **can't** use your **local file sytem** with **distcp**. An alternative could be configure a FTP server in your machine that hadoop cluster can read. The performance depends on the network and the protocol used (ftp with hadoop has a very bad performance).

Use **hdfs dfs -put** command could be better for small amount of data but it isn't work in parallel like distcp.